# check url contains pagination id

Tags: java, string, pagination

iam given with a some-url which may or may-not contains integer at last i want to check
whether integer is present and if present what is the value of it.

ex: `localhost:8200/videos`
`localhost:8200/videos/1`
`localhost:8200/videos/2`
`localhost:8200/videos/popular-entertainment`
`localhost:8200/videos/popular-entertainment/1`
`localhost:8200/videos/popular-entertainment/2`
`localhost:8200/videos-funny/popular-entertainment`
`localhost:8200/videos-funny/popular-entertainment/1`
`localhost:8200/videos-funny/popular-entertainment/2`
`localhost:8200/videos-funny/popular-entertainment/3`

i want get the pagination id at last of url if present in java

Comment: So you want to check whether the url ends with a slash followed by one or more digits and get those digits?

Comment: yes basically i want to check url end with slash(/) followed by numberic digit but whole url is string so i cannot know it ends with numeric digit

Comment: Sure you can. A simple regex like `/(\d+)$` should do the trick. If it matches you can then extract the group and parse it as a number.